# How to use the python make the Escape Sequence to Character Entities

Tags: python, html

I am a fresh pythoner, thank for help me.
I just want to make the Escape Sequence to Character Entities, like the `&lt;` change to `<`, but one HTML page have many different Escape Sequence, I can not write many replace statement,like:

```
str = str.replace('&nbsp;', ' ')

...............many code.........

str = str.replace('&lt;', '<')
str = str.replace('&gt;', '>')
```

It is so long....I just want to have a fun or def, that can make the problem easily.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`HTMLParser.HTMLParser`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html#HTMLParser.HTMLParser):

```
>>> from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
>>> # from html.parser import HTMLParser # In Python 3.x
>>> 
>>> parser = HTMLParser()
>>> parser.unescape('&gt;_&lt;')
u'>_<'
>>> parser.unescape('&#48;&#49;&#x32;')
u'012'
```

**NOTE**: `HTMLParser.unescape('&nbsp;')` returns NO-BREAK SPACE (U+00A0) instead of SPACE.

```
>>> parser.unescape('&nbsp;')
u'\xa0'
```

BTW, Don't use `str` as a variable name, it shadows a builtin function [`str`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str).

Comment: but if i want to change many others escape sequence, mayby the str have many many ES, what should I do ?

Comment: @671coder, What is ES?   What means others escape sequence?

Comment: Oh I am sorry , es = escape sequence, and I just edit it on python2.7

Comment: @671coder, What does other escape sequence means? If you mean something like `&#48`, `&#x32`, .., HTMLParser.unescape can handle them.

Comment: I am sorry that my english is very bad, I just want know what function can recognise all the Escape Sequence in "str", and change it to normal sequence..

Comment: @671coder, I gave you example code in the answer. Do you want `str = parser.unescape(str)` ?